# Trouble running TASKKILL from GitBash

Tags: windows, git-bash, taskkill

I'm trying to create a function in my **.bashrc** to run in gitbash. The command I'm trying to run is:

```
cmd '/C TASKKILL /fi "WINDOWTITLE eq  Windows Task Manager"'
```

I'll be changing the "Windows Task Manager" bit, but just to show what I'm trying. The command (TASKKILL /fi "WINDOWTITLE eq  Windows Task Manager") works fine when I run it through Windows cmd, but when I run from gitbash, I get this error message:

```
ERROR: Invalid argument/option - 'eq'.
Type "TASKKILL /?" for usage.
```

As I said, it works fine in cmd, so I'm thinking it's something to do with the quotation marks. I've also tried the following, which also fails:

```
cmd "/C TASKKILL /fi \"WINDOWTITLE eq  Windows Task Manager\""
```

I *could* put the command in a .bat file and run that (cmd "/C pathtofile/script.bat") and that works, but I'd prefer to run it straight from the **.bashrc**, if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
cmd "/C TASKKILL /fi "WINDOWTITLE eq  Windows Task Manager""
```

It seems like it shouldn't work due to how the quotation marks are nested, but it does.

Comment: @zodac you should mark this as the correct answer, it does work.