# Passing windows slash (/) based parameters to a program from bash script

Tags: windows, bash, msysgit

I'm trying to run the following from my bash script. *(bash installed via msysgit)*

```
taskkill /IM ssh-agent.exe
```

The output I get on the screen from `taskkill` is:

```
ERROR: Invalid argument/option - 'C:/Program Files/Git/IM'.
Type "TASKKILL /?" for usage.
```

The executible is running, but the `/IM` is being expanded regardless of what I try to do to escape it...

---

I've tried using `\/IM` but then it sends `\/IM` without escaping the slash, I've tried a few different ways of running it through eval, cmd /c start, etc... but they all seem to have issues.  I've also tried `set -o noglob`, which also didn't work.  neither did `$'\057/'IM` or similar attempts...

Comment: Maybe try `.\SomeExecutable.exe "/foo"`

Comment: @l'L'l `SomeExecutable` is running fine, it's the fact that the parameter coming into `SomeExecutable` is `/some/path/to/foo` instead of *just* `/foo`

Comment: Oh I see... escaping it seems logical as you had; my only other suggestion might be to try it in quotes.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

*Since my comment actually provided the answer, I'll post it.*

How about escaping a forward slash to another forward slash like `//`. It works for me when I execute this command where I escaped the `/r` parameter:
`start C:/folder/beep 2000 250 100 //r 3`

Source: http://oldwiki.mingw.org/index.php/switches%20with%20forward%20slashes

> ## Minimalist GNU for Windows
>
> **Passing switches with forward slashes under MSYS**
>
> In MSYS a command line argument of "/c" is interpreted as the C:
>   drive, so to pass any argument beginning with a forward slash you need
>   to use two forward slashes. For example, to use this command in MSYS:
>
> `cmd /c echo foo`
>
> Use:
>
> `cmd //c echo foo`
>
> If you need to have the windows-style of a path in a shell script, you
>   can do
>
> `x=$(cd /unix/path && cmd //c cd)`
>
> The x var now contains the windows equivalent path to /unix/path

Comment: The trick for converting unix path to windows path in a variable is very useful. However, you should be aware that if `/unix/path` is a symblink, e.g. created by `mklink /j c:\unix\path d:\unix\path`, your variable will show the linked location `d:\unix\path`

Comment: @sveinbr: Thank god msys2 comes with `cygpath` again, eh? I remember being thoroughly frustrated at some version of msys whose maintainers had left `cygpath` out, apparently just because "[You should not need such a thingy, because Msys automagically translates Path 
names, even in the environment.](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw/mailman/message/8686481/)".

Comment: However, if we are running a huge bash script in MinGW, we cannot modify the script to make it working with mingw syntax...

Answer (score 5):

After hours of looking for various searches like "disable bash file expansion" and the like, I found it by searching specifically for `"bash" "windows" taskkill` the executable I was trying to run, I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34179983/43906), which finally worked for me.

```
cmd " /c taskkill /F /IM ssh-agent.exe"
```

Comment: Can't you simply escape the forward slash with another forward slash like `//`? It seems to work for me, source: http://oldwiki.mingw.org/index.php/switches%20with%20forward%20slashes

Comment: @M.Mimpen thanks so much, that actually works for me too... I'd tried `\/` and can't think of how many other permutations to try and get bash to not use path completion.   I was trying to make my windows start-ssh-agent match the cmd based one...