# Bind to docker socket on Windows

Tags: docker

On *nix systems, it is possible to bind-mount the docker socket from the host machine to the VM by doing something like this:

`docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock ...`

Is there an equivalent way to do this when running docker on a windows host?

---

I tried various combinations like:

`docker run -v tcp://127.0.0.1:2376:/var/run/docker.sock ...`

`docker run -v "tcp://127.0.0.1:2376":/var/run/docker.sock ...`

`docker run -v localhost:2376:/var/run/docker.sock ...`

none of these have worked.

Comment: On Windows docker runs inside a VirtualBox VM, so it wouldn't be able to bind network resources from your Windows.

Comment: I can't get it to work in 2019. I just opened this issue: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/4642

Answer (score 169):

For Docker for Windows following seems to be working:

`-v //var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock`

Comment: This really works!! I have been trying to get this working forever. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Some of the above answers seem like they aren't referring to running Windows containers on Docker for Windows. When I try to run the standard command for doing this:

`docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock` 

I get the following error:

`docker: Error response from daemon: invalid bind mount spec "//var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock": invalid volume specification: '\\var\run\docker.sock:\var\run\docker.sock'`

The error makes sense because as I'm on Windows, trying to run a Windows container the paths don't make sense.

Comment: @JoshWittner: have you found a solution to make the Docker Socket available inside Windows Containers with Windows Hosts?

Comment: This works indeed, do you now the reason? Is there any official documentation for this?

Comment: After 2 days of googling, I finally found the answer!

Comment: It really works when you use `docker run`, but it wont work when you use it in docker-compose file

Comment: @Kevin It's probably a bit late, but Docker on Windows actually runs in a virtual machine, so this command is likely mapping to that VM, rather than a real host machine disk.

Comment: @john of course you are right about the VM (and I knew this), I was wondering about the leading `/`. So you mean the leading `/` is a hack for referencing the VM?

Comment: @Kevin I believe so. If you use `-v //:/testfolder` and inspect /testfolder in the docker container, you can see things like `/usr`, `/bin`, `/mnt`, etc.

Comment: I believe it's not magic its just path expansion in git bash on windows. Using / in front of the parameter disables path expansion. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34647591/passing-windows-slash-based-parameters-to-a-program-from-bash-script

Took me a while to figure this out but thanks to this answer I saved a lot of time. Thanks everyone!!

Comment: Anyone know is there's a "2018" solution for this (Since Docker on Windows no longer uses a VM to run Windows containers?)

Comment: @MikeChristensen, i have tested using the hyper-v enabled docker and it works just fine, but to do the same with docker-compose, one must set the environment `COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1` either in CLI or a `.env` file at the same location as the project's docker-compose.yml, [source](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1829#issuecomment-417376091)

Comment: @alexander-chichenin Here's a big hug :)

Comment: What's gonna happen if I `docker attach` to myself LOL

Comment: It is not working for me :( I'm running: docker run -d -p 49001:8080 -u 0 -v D:/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home:z -v //var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -t jenkins/jenkins

Comment: Thanks!! Been trying to do the Jenkins tutorial and this is what got it going!

Answer (score 22):

As the [Docker documentation states](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/):

> If you are using Docker Machine on Mac or Windows, your Engine daemon
>   has only limited access to your OS X or Windows filesystem. Docker
>   Machine tries to auto-share your `/Users` (OS X) or `C:\Users` (Windows)
>   directory. So, you can mount files or directories on OS X using:

```
docker run -v /Users/<path>:/<container path> ...
```

> On Windows, mount directories using:

```
docker run -v /c/Users/<path>:/<container path> ...
```

> **All other paths come from your virtual machine’s filesystem**, so if you
>   want to make some other host folder available for sharing, you need to
>   do additional work. In the case of VirtualBox you need to make the
>   host folder available as a shared folder in VirtualBox. Then, you can
>   mount it using the Docker -v flag.

With all that being said, you can still use the:

```
docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock ...
```

The first `/var/run/docker.sock` refers to the same path in your `boot2docker` virtual machine.

For example, when I run my own Jenkins image using the following command in a Windows machine:

```
$ docker run -dP -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock alidehghanig/jenkins
```

I can still talk to the Docker Daemon in the host machine using the typical `docker` commands. For example, when I run `docker ps` in the Jenkins container, I can see running containers in the host machine:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE  COMMAND   CREATED  STATUS  PORTS        NAMES
65311731f446   jen... "/bi.."   10...    Up 10.. 0.0.0.0:..  jenkins
```

Answer (score 10):

Just to top it off on the answers provided earlier

When using docker-compose, one must set the `COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1` by either:

1) create a `.env` file at the same location as the project's docker-compose.yml file

2) in the CLI `set COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1`

before running the docker-compose up command.

[source](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1829#issuecomment-417376091)

Answer (score 7):

This never worked for me on Windows 10 even if it is a linux container:

```
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

But this did:

```
-v /usr/local/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker
```

Solution taken from this issue i opened: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/4642

Answer (score 7):

To bind to a Windows container you need to use pipes.

```
-v \\.\pipe\docker_engine:\\.\pipe\docker_engine
```

Answer (score 5):

Some containers (eg. portainer) work fine with `-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock`
The jenkins container required `--user root` permissions on the `docker run` command to successfully access the Docker UNIX socket (using Docker-Desktop on Windows).

> By default, a unix domain socket (or IPC socket) is created at
>   `/var/run/docker.sock`, requiring either `root` permission, or `docker`
>   group membership.

Source: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#daemon-socket-option

`--group-add docker` had **no** effect using Docker-Desktop on Windows.

Answer (score 5):

What it was suitable for me in `Windows 10` was:

```
 -v "\\.\pipe\docker_engine:\\.\pipe\docker_engine"
```

Have in mind that I was trying to access to portainer that I do recommend a lot it's a great app. For that I use this command:

```
docker run -d -p 9000:9000 -v "\\.\pipe\docker_engine:\\.\pipe\docker_engine" portainer/portainer
```

And then just go to:

```
http://localhost:9000/
```

Answer (score 1):

it works well :

```
docker run -it -v //var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /usr/local/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker ubuntu
```

Comment: the author is on windows, so no "/var/run/docker.sock" and "/usr/local/bin/docker" does not exists.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of the already accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me on **Windows 11**;

```
-v //./pipe/docker_engine://./pipe/docker_engine
```

Let me explain the reason I'm posting this is, I've tried the back-slash version which is written in the answers above in this post, and that is not working. I've tried the followings;

```
-v \\.\pipe\docker_engine:\\.\pipe\docker_engine
```

neither wrapped with quotes as follows worked;

```
-v "\\.\pipe\docker_engine:\\.\pipe\docker_engine"
```

Popped out this error;

docker: Error response from daemon: .\pipe\docker_engine%!(EXTRA string=is not a valid Windows path).

Answer (score 0):

I never made it worked myself, but i know it works on windows container on docker for windows server 2016 using this technique:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#daemon-socket-option

We actually have at the shop vsts-agents on windows containers that uses the host docker like that:

```
# listen using the default unix socket, and on 2 specific IP addresses on this host.    
$ sudo dockerd -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock -H tcp://192.168.59.106 -H tcp://10.10.10.2

# then you can execute remote docker commands (from container to host for example)
$ docker -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 ps
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what actually made it work for me

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v D:\docker-data\jenkins:/var/jenkins_home -v /usr/local/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -u root jenkins/jenkins:lts
```