# Use a docker sdk to send commands to the docker machine from a web app

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-machine, docker-api

I'm new to Docker and I have some difficulties to understand how I should use it.

For now, I'm wondering if that makes sense to attempt sending commands to a docker machine on my computer from the client side script of a javascript web app using an SDK like Dockerode.

I installed Docker CE for windows (17.06.0-ce) and Docker Toolbox, and I ran a container on the default machine using the docker terminal. Now I'm wondering if the commands I typed could be sent from a web app using NodeJS. I tried using this code:

```
import Docker from 'dockerode';

const docker = new Docker({host: 'myDefaultMachineHost'});

export function createLocalDb () {

    docker.pull('someImageFromDockerHub', function (err, stream) {
      if (err) console.log("Catch : " + err.toString());
          stream.pipe(process.stdout, {end: true});

      stream.on('end', function() {
        //run the container
      }).catch(function (err) {
            console.log("Catch : " + err.toString());
        });
    });
}
```

But that doesn't work(stream.pipe throws an error). Am I misunderstanding the context in which I'm supposed to use dockerode ?

Thanks for your explanations !

Answer (score 0):

**In short**: You need change your code to this `const docker = new Docker({socketPath: '/var/run/docker.sock'});` and add docker socket inside your container.

**Theory:**

You have docker socket inside your local machine. You should add this socket inside your docker container. The [volume](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/volumes/) is your solution.

Image for visualization this issue:

[image]

**Implementation with arguments**

This is simple task for Linux/Mac user. They can do

```
docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock ...
```

On Windows you need run

```
docker run -v //var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock ...
```

More details in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36765138/bind-to-docker-socket-on-windows).

**Implementation with Dockerfile**

Also, you can add to your Dockerfile `VOLUME` instruction.

On Linux/Mac it should be line like this:

```
VOLUME /var/run/docker.sock /var/run/docker.sock
```

I don't know who it will be on Windows, I use Mac.