# Airflow: How to setup log directory?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I upload a dag file to the web page and when I click `'Graph View'` -> `${my_dag}` -> `'View Log'`, it shows:

```
*** Log file isn't local.
*** Fetching here: http://:8793/log/demo_dag/hello_task/2018-11-14T15:06:00
*** Failed to fetch log file from worker.

*** Reading remote logs...
*** Unsupported remote log location.
```

I have checked the `airflow.cfg` and find these config info:

```
worker_log_server_port = 8793
base_log_folder = /root/airflow/logs
```

My question is:

1. How to setup IP address for log service (Only port is setup)?
2. I have setup directory for log service, why does it still go to `/log/..` ?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the file path to the log in `/log`?

Comment: hey @joeb Thanks for your reply. The log file path is `/root/airflow/logs` (as in config file), but this path has full permissions (777).

Comment: What is the path to the file in your `/log` directory that you say has Airflow logging messages in it?

Comment: @joeb thanks for your reply. The path is `/root/airflow/logs`, as shown in the config file.

Comment: In your second question "I have setup directory for log service, why does it still go to `/log/..`" -- What is the full path to the file in `/log/..` that you are seeing which contains Airflow logging?

Answer (score 1):

This can happen when the task status was manually changed (likely through the "Mark Success" option) and the task never receives a `hostname` value on the record.

The webserver is attempting to reach out to a server, with no name, to get logs for a task that never ran.

PS: Be careful running processes as the `root` user.

Comment: I don't think I changed the task status. Actually, all tasks keep running and never finished. I am trying to find reasons and logs are not available.

Comment: What is the status of the task that you're viewing?

Answer (score 1):

I've been getting this error, fix it by correcting the socket volume path:

```
WARNING - OSError while attempting to symlink the latest log directory
```

In windows the volume will go with a double bar like this:

```
volumes:
  - //var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

[Bind to docker socket on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36765138/bind-to-docker-socket-on-windows/41005007#41005007)

[Setting up Airflow to run with Docker Swarm’s orchestration](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/setting-up-airflow-to-run-with-docker-swarms-orchestration-b16459cd03a2)