# root:OSError while attempting to symlink the latest log directory - Apache Airflow

Tags: python, windows-10, airflow

I am using Windows 10, python 3.6.4, and apache-airflow 1.10.2

I am trying to use Apache-Airflow for creating a workflow for my data pipeline. When I import airflow (the first time in a new session), I keep running into the following error:

```
import airflow  
  **WARNING:root:OSError while attempting to symlink the latest log directory**  
import airflow  
  (No Error)
```

When I try to import aiflow again, I do not get this error. I checked my config file and it is pointing to the right directory (C:\Users\user\airflow, where my logs folder is).

To solve this error, when it comes to creating the symbolic link to the log folder, I am not sure how to approach this or if I should even do this manually?

I also create a environment variables to my airflow folder.Please let me know if more details are needed!

Comment: I assume you are mounting windows directory into linux, that must be the cause. Probably a proper solution would be to sshfs a linux directory into windows.

Comment: today i have tried. i understood what is the problem. basically airflow stores logs locally if remote location not setup. so path format is different in windows and Linux . like User\username where as Linux user/username link and more is is given though only one config file still its is considering \ once and / once for the same file

Comment: For the sake of those who encounter this same error while using Azure Files, the trick is to enable the `mfsymlinks` mount option, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-troubleshoot-linux-file-connection-problems for details

Comment: Posible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53315630/airflow-how-to-setup-log-directory/66962793#66962793

Answer (score 2):

Airflow does not work on Windows directly. Instead, you can run it from a Linux virtual machine, Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL), or Docker container.

To run it from a virtual machine, you can download [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) along with the latest [ubuntu-desktop ISO](https://ubuntu.com/download) file. Now, you can create a virtual machine and install Airflow against it.