# Where is locate pidfile | docker for windows | docker.pid

Tags: config, pid, docker-for-windows, docker

I would like to have docker inside docker for use CI-agent. But for it I need to share `docker.pid` file inside docker container and I can't find that file in this path `C:\ProgramData\docker.pid` and even I try to add this in docker daemon config:

```
{
...
  "pidfile": "C:\\docker.pid",
...
}
```

And after a restart, that file didn't appear.
Could you please help me?

Also tried different variant in config file like `"C:\docker.pid"`, `"C:/docker.pid"`. The same behavior.
The docker logs is clean about creating or removing `docker.pid` file.

### Software info

Windows Version: 10 1809 build 17763

Docker for Windows Version: 2.0.0.2 31259

### Expected behavior

Create pid file in path `C:\docker.pid`

### Actual behavior

The file is absent

---

Also created an issue in github
https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/3741

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to run Docker inside docker.
These two topics help me:

https://forums.docker.com/t/solved-using-docker-inside-another-container/12222/3

[Bind to docker socket on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36765138/bind-to-docker-socket-on-windows)

I needed `docker.sock` file and it locate `//var/run/docker.sock` so

`-v //var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock`

resolve my problem.