# docker.from_env() return FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker

Docker(19.03.12) running in Windows 10.
a container with Python 3.7.3, pip install docker(4.3.1),
when run docker.from_env(), it returns fail.
Anyone can help? Thanks!

```
Python 3.7.3 (default, Jul 25 2020, 13:03:44)
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>> import docker
    >>> docker.from_env()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 354, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1244, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1290, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1239, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 966, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/docker/transport/unixconn.py", line 43, in connect
    sock.connect(self.unix_socket)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: Your client is unable to connect to docker daemon. Check whether daemon is running at the expected location, config, etc.

Comment: docker is running. I found there is no file /var/run/docker.sock, and sock.connect want to connect with this, so it report no file. could you please help why no this file?

Comment: Check your config. May be it's using a custom socket path or listening on tcp only. Restart it for good measure.

Answer (score 0):

answer was here:
[How do you mount the docker socket on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57466568/how-do-you-mount-the-docker-socket-on-windows)

the 2nd answer works for me.
docker run --rm -it -v "//var/run/docker.sock://var/run/docker.sock" image_with_docker docker version

I did not use quotation mark. only: (there are double / at first place both for host path and container path)
docker run --rm -it -v //var/run/docker.sock://var/run/docker.sock image_with_docker docker version