# Unable to mount /var/run/docker.sock from inside linux distribution (wsl 2)

Tags: linux, docker, centos, windows-subsystem-for-linux, docker-volume

I am unable to mount `docker.sock` when creating a container in WSL 2:

```
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

I get the following error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: not a directory.
```

When navigating to `/var/run`, I can clearly see `docker.sock` being present, so I am unsure about why I am getting this error. `docker ps` correctly shows all the running containers.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bind to docker socket on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36765138/bind-to-docker-socket-on-windows)

Comment: could explain in what situation you are using wsl2 and centos together?

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a volume by passing this flag to the `docker run` command:

`-v //var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock`