# bash script aws cloudfront create-invalidation path is incorrect

Tags: bash, git, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I'm new to bash, trying to create invalidation in the bash script by simply calling

```
aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id XXX --profile XXX --path /planning/index.html
```

Works fine in cmd but not in git bash. Must be some escape characters problem but Im not quite getting how it shoud be.

**Update**: Error message Im getting in bash `when calling the CreateInvalidation operation: Your request contains one or more invalid invalidation paths`

**Solved**: Solved by providing `cli-input-json`

````
aws cloudfront create-invalidation --profile $PROFILE --cli-input-json "{\"DistributionId\":\"MY_DISTRIBUTION_ID\",\"InvalidationBatch\":{\"Paths\":{\"Quantity\":1,\"Items\":[\"/planning/index.html\"]},\"CallerReference\":\"$(date +%s)\"}}"```
````

Comment: What do you mean with "git bash" ?

Comment: I'm working on windows, so executing scripts in [git bash](https://gitforwindows.org/)

Comment: Im trying to escape slash character by passing `--paths "/\planning/\index.html"` but it is getting parsed to `"//planning/index.html"`

Comment: Slash is not a special character in the shell. Your code looks fine as far as Bash is concerned; probably an AWS problem. (You are backslash-escaping `p` and `i` though, not the slashes. If the code in the comment is the one you are actually having trouble with, why isn't it in the question?)

Comment: What error message are you getting? It might help to add that to the question as well.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is not aws problem because im executing exactly the same command with no modification in cmd and it works fine

Comment: @tripleee code in the comment, it is just im getting mad trying different combinations. the actual code im having trouble with in desc

Comment: I can workaround this problem by moving invalidation path in json file and then ```aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id XXX --profile XXX --invalidation-batch file://INVALIDATION_FILE.json``` but it is just so annoying to have such overhead for single file invalidation

Comment: goolged though, seems like its popular solution in bash scripts to apply invalidation using json file e.g. [here](https://www.mattcrampton.com/blog/invalidating_all_files_from_a_cloudfront_distribution_cache_from_the_command_line/) but I still hope it is possible to do without json file

Answer (score 2):

For me this worked in git bash:

```
aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id XXX --path //index.html
```

The slash must be a double slash. It may be related to this issue:
[Passing windows slash (/) based parameters to a program from bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34647591/passing-windows-slash-based-parameters-to-a-program-from-bash-script)